# Using T-SQL, how to convert date format mmm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

Using TSQL, what's the most efficient way to convert a datatype string formatted date 'mmm-dd-yyyy' to  data type date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Example:

Original date: Jan-31-2013

Converted date: 2013-01-31

I was looking for the conversion in this document but no success. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: `Jan-31-2013` is it string or datetime (date) datatype?

Comment: Is your “Original date” a column in your database? What is its data type? What data type are you trying to convert it to? A DateTime? VarChar? NVarchar? Why are you trying to “convert” it at all? What's wrong with using dates as dates; TSQL deals with date types fine without any conversion.

Comment: The original date will be passed in as a String

Comment: The original date is a variable in String format. It will be converted to a DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your problem, not sure if there's a more efficient solution though?

```
declare @DateTime as varchar(max)
set @DateTime = 'Jan-31-2013';
select cast(substring(@DateTime,8,4) + '-' + substring(@DateTime,1,3) + '-' + substring(@DateTime,5,2) as date)
```

[image: SQL Result Image]

Answer (score 5):

Most effective way returned as date:

```
select convert(date, replace('Jan-31-2013', '-', ' '), 0)
```

Most effective way returned as char(10):

```
select convert(char(10),convert(date, replace('Jan-31-2013', '-', ' '), 0), 126)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change date Format from MM/DD/YY to MM/DD/YYY:

```
SELECT Substring(trans_date, 4, 2)+'-'+Substring(trans_date, 1, 2)+'-'+'20'+SUBSTRing(trans_date, 7, 2) ,* from TempTable
```